# Dell Inspirion 5570 win10 acts weird on a certain wireless network

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, drivers

I am not sure this question belongs here but I have no idea where else to ask help for this problem. 
I am experiencing weird behavior from my Dell Inspirion 5570, win 10 Home student license, regarding the wireless driver on a certain network. This type of behavior does not happen on my home network( which is slower than this network as it doesn't reach 100Mbps) or on mobile hotspot or any other network I have tried. 
Behaviour:

1. it doesn't have the upload/ download speed as fast as the network is,I have tested this with another laptop(Huawei MateBook D14 2020 ) which gets up to 200-300Mbps on wireless network and close to 500Mbps on LAN , both tests done with ookla speedtest.
2. it stops browser pages like facebook, youtube, discord from loading and appears to have an error on the network but other pages or searches ar fine at the same time( for ex: I can search any word or meaning or go to shopping pages but I can't access facebook's feed in the same browser or on different browsers, I have tested both)
   I believe it is an issue with the driver for networks, I have tried updating it, rollback, change setting on it but nothing seems to work.

The driver is : Qualcomm QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Adapter

Looked up on dell.com support for another driver for this laptop but this is the only one and I have the latest version. 
I have no idea where to go next or how to solve this, any  help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Try first: TCP/IP Reset:  Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
Then: netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
Then: ipconfig /flushdns
Then: restart the computer .  If TCP/IP Reset does not solve the issue, consider a decent USB Wireless adapter to see if that works better

Comment: I tried with a USB adapter, the same one used for the Huawei laptop but it didn't changed anything. I also used the ethernet port on the laptop for wired networking but no results. It's weird because the desktop apps work, it's just the browsers that don't want to work.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Much broken. Try a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation link. Use the second link on the page and run in place to do the repair. Start with Keep Everything.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: Would this affect any work I have on my laptop or the apps I use? I am turning in my thesis in a month and I don't want to lose everything I have on it.

Comment: I have used Windows 10 Repair Install: Keep Everything and not lost anything. I would definitely back up documents first (I keep documents on two machines).  So the process does work. You may wish to wait until your thesis is complete.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I will wait until my thesis is finished. I do backup my files  but not regularly and it would be too much to backup without filtering first.